# Why does Serverfault use Dynect Platform? And should I too?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

Lots of domains use Dynect Platform (Zendesk.com, Stackoverflow.com, Serverfault.com, ...). **Could you, please, explain to me what Dynect Platform (and similiar applications) does? And when to use Dynect Platform?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Among the things Dynect Platform does is forward requests to 'serverfault.com' to the data-center that is closer to your location. This is very handy when you have more than one datacenter, such as one on the east coast and west coast.  And it makes adding more (Australia, Africa) a lot easier.

It also can do load-balancing, so requests go different places based on load. As well as DNSSEC on the DNS service it provides, which is a fantastic way to ensure that what it tells you really is what it should be telling you.

You use it when you need geographic load balancing, or location based servicing. Among other things.

Answer (score 3):

[Jeff Atwood posted on the Stack Overflow blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/new-dns-provider/) with background about why they chose Dynamic Network Services as their DNS provider.

I can tell you that I've used them for my own domain and several Customers' domains for years and love their service. Your mileage may vary, but they've been economical, reliable, and friendly to work with for me.